# Store strings with special characters as enum values in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, special-characters

In Rails 5, the [enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) value type can only accept symbols, i.e. immutable "strings" with letters and digits.

How would you best use enum values in Rails, which have to be shown also with their special characters like e.g. `'Hip-Hop/Rap'` included in the enum field `genre`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use quotes around symbol text if it contains special characters.

```
[:classical, :pop, :'Hip-Hop/Rap']
```

Comment: What would be the state of generated query methods for enum?

Comment: @Anwar The use of the symbol in a rails where clause would be `where(genre: :'Hip-Hop/Rap') and the SQL generated will be "WHERE genre = 2" as rails will substitute the symbol for the equivalent expected column value.